# Xamarin iOS app not trusted on iPhone 13, OK on iPhone SE?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022, code-signing-entitlements

I'm working on a Xamarin iOS app.

I do not understand why, but using the same signing configuration (Automatic developer identity/Automatic provisioning profile), the app is deployed by VS and launches fine on my iPhone SE (2nd Gen) running iOS 16.1.1.

However it is deployed but is not trusted on my iPhone 13 running iOS 16.2.

Here is a screen capture that shows the infamous icon and app prefix with cloud and row pointing below.

[image]

If I try to run the app if tells me that it can't be verified (sorry this is in French):

[image]

I doubt that this problem comes from the app itself because it runs fine in the simulator and on one device with the same major OS version.

What is wrong here?

Comment: How did you get the app onto the iPhone 13? Did you build it in Xcode with the phone connected to your Mac?  Is the iPhone 13 registered in your developer account and included in the app's provisioning profile?

Comment: There is nothing regarding Xcode here. It's all about Visual Studio for Mac and automatic signing, similar to what Xcode does. The deployment is done upon build by Visual Studio itself.

Comment: It will be using Xcode under the covers.  All builds for iOS ultimately need to use Apple's toolchain.  You need to ensure that the device you are targeting is registered in your developer account and included in the provisioning profile regardless of how you initiate the build.  I haven't used Xamarin but every other cross platform tool I have seen generates an Xcode project

Comment: I had to add the device and add a provisioning profile manually to make it run. I agree with you that the apple toolchain to sign the bundle is mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to provision the iOS device,

1. [Free provisioning for Xamarin.iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos) through XCode. If you do not have a paid Apple developer account, you could use this way.
2. [Manual provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos). When generating a new provisioning file, remember to also include the device you want to deplay.

For more info, you could refer to [Device provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/).